# Looking for assistance with PyCharm and Robot Framework

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I’m new to Pycharm & Robot Framework and I’ve got almost everything setup and working except, how to configure the Run command to run my xxx.robot file instead of individual test cases within the robot file.

I have PyCharm setup as follows:
-   F8 is mapped to Run

- I have the following plugins enabled.
  -- Intellibot @SelenimLibrary Patched
  -- Robot Framework Support
  -- RobotPy
  -- Run Robot Framework file
  -- Run Robot Framework Testcase

As previously mentioned, pressing F8 will attempt run the current Testcase but it fails because it's not truly running the robot code. I've also tried configuring an External Tool but I couldn't get that to work. I really want to figure out how to get Run to work.

If you have any suggestions, plz let me know.